# Recreate migration when making a change to the model

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

I have spent a lot of time writing ADO.NET code recently.  I have moved back to EF Core and I am now looking at the config below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonSport>().HasKey(sc => new { sc.PersonId, sc.SportId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<Sport>()
           .ToTable("Sport")
           .HasDiscriminator<string>("SportType")
           .HasValue<Football>("Football")
           .HasValue<Running>("Running");

            modelBuilder.Entity<PersonSport>()
                .HasOne<Person>(sc => sc.Person)
                .WithMany(s => s.PersonSport)
                .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.PersonId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            modelBuilder.Entity<PersonSport>()
                .HasOne<Sport>(sc => sc.Sport)
                .WithMany(s => s.PersonSport)
                .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.SportId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            var navigation = modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(ConsoleApp1.Person.PersonSport));
            navigation.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

If I delete a Person or a Sport then the approapriate PersonSport records are deleted because DeleteBehaviour.Cascade is set for OnDelete.  If I want to change this to DeleteBehaviour.Restrict, then I have to recreate the migrations and update the database.  Why? The reason I ask why is because PersonSportContext.OnModelCreating runs every time I start the program.

I realise this is quite a simple question.  I have been away from the ORM for a while and am much more experienced with ADO.NET.

I have spent the last hour or so reading through several similar questions on here, however I have not found the answer to my specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Migrations. It's just a convenient way to ensure that your EF model and database schema are in sync. Some other ways to keep them in sync:

- Reverse engineer your model (Scaffold-DbContext or `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`) every time you change the database schema.
- Manually make changes to your EF model and database schema at the same time.